# Material-UI: How to put two Date Pickers on same line?

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-ui

I am creating a form using [material-ui](http://material-ui.com/).

I can display two SelectFields on the same line with:

```
<SelectField floatingLabelText="Selection One" menuItems={menuItems} />
<SelectField floatingLabelText="Selection Two" menuItems={menuItems} />
```

or on two lines with:

```
<SelectField floatingLabelText="Selection One" menuItems={menuItems} /><br />
<SelectField floatingLabelText="Selection Two" menuItems={menuItems} />
```

However, the following code results in two lines:

```
<DatePicker floatingLabelText="Start Date" />
<DatePicker floatingLabelText="Completion Date" />
```

How can I display two DatePickers on the same line (without using minDate and maxDate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but enclosing the DatePickers in a table works:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <DatePicker floatingLabelText="Start Date" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <DatePicker floatingLabelText="Completion Date" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```